# SQL Server 2019 Removing user from database results in external libraries folder error

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask what can be done in order not  to receive following message that appears in SQL Server log every time a user is removed from a database on SQL Server 2019:

> Couldn't remove the user (n) from database (n) from the external
>   libraries folder, error: 0x80070003

I assume it is related to installed feature "Machine Learning Services and Language Extensions" which is installed?

Comment: I've got the same issue using EXEC sp_executeSQL @stmt; the user is dropped but the log shows the error message... "Couldn't remove the user 11 from database 14 from the external libraries folder, error: 0x80070003"